# SSIS - Copy Excel sheet and delete from old

Tags: excel, dynamic, ssis

I need some advice around copying Excel files and then keeping a 'template' once it's moved. I have a bunch of Excel files that need to be loaded into SQL. The names might differ, i.e. Excel_Test1, Excel_Test2. These files are processed into SQL. Once this is done I have to copy them into an Archive folder. The problem is if I move instead of copy I get the error in my SSIS package where it says object doesn't exist. What can I do to ensure it doesn't happen? Is there a way to copy the files to archive, and then create a dynamic Excel sheet for next time? Or is there an easier way of doing this? Steps are:

1. Truncate Staging Table.
2. Load first table.
3. Load second table.
4. Move / copy files to archive.

I hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep one version of file in Template folder
(it can contain fake data if it make sense), then copy actual file to archive after processing, and then override the actual file with file from Template folder.